# Remove white space on xml fragments

Tags: c#-4.0

IS it possible to remove white spances between xml tags below **without using LINQ** please?

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression like this Replace all that matches `>\s*<` to `><` This will remove the spaces. The character class `\s` matches spaces, tabs, and line breaks.

In C#

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("INPUT", ">\s*<", "><")
```